# $scope$watch change one var if another changed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-watch

so i have to scope objects

```
    $scope.hf_directory = data.features;
    $scope.brylanty = data.features;
```

Actually they contain the same data, but i am trying to know how watch works so then i can use it in my project.

And i would like to watch hf_directory on which i use filter:search, so it would update scope.brylanty after typing something in input fiels ng-model="search"

i tried to do something like this but not making any changes

```
  $scope.$watch('hf_directory', function (newValue, oldValue, $scope) {
if(newValue) {
  $scope.brylanty = newValue;
}
});
```

Both scope objects are displayed by ng-repeat loop, on first i use filter:search on another nothing, i know i could just use another filter:search, but i want to learn how to use watch ;)

My objects are geojson data, they containt the same value, geojson look like below:

```
  {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "SomeName"}, "geometry": { "type":      "Point", "coordinates": [ 11.410585, 11.293361 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": , "SecondName": { "type": "Point",   "coordinates": [ 11.410585, 11.293361 ] } }, .......

]
}
```

After Your advices guys i tried this

```
 $scope.search = {};

 $scope.$watch('search', function (newVal) {

        $scope.brylanty = newVal;

});
```

And this

```
$scope.$watch('search', function (newValue, oldValue, $scope) {
    if (newValue) {
        $scope.brylanty = newValue;
    }
});
```

But without any good results, in both cases when i start typing something object brylanty is disappearing?

Comment: What is `hf_directory` ? How does it look like? Is it an object?

Comment: hf_directory and brylanty are geojsons,a list of object.

Comment: YOu need to use third argument for object equality in the watch.i.e `$scope.$watch('hf_directory', function (newValue, oldValue, $scope)..., true);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make changes upon typing something in the input ng-model="search" then ideally you should be watching the search variable. It should be

```
$scope.$watch('search', function (newValue, oldValue, $scope) {
    if(newValue) {
         $scope.brylanty = newValue;
    }
});
```

This can also be written as (for 2 lines less)

```
$scope.$watch('search', function (newValue, oldValue, $scope) {
     $scope.brylanty = (newValue) ? newValue : $scope.brylanty;
});
```

alternatively you could use ng-change in your input field and have

```
<input ng-model="search" ng-change="brylanty = (search) ? search : brylanty"/>
```

Watching hf_directory has no effect since typing in search doesn't affect it.

Edit: if you really want to watch hf_directory and it's an object/array then use

```
$scope.$watchCollection()
```

with the same arguments

Comment: I used your first advice with search, but then when i type anything object brylanty is disappearing? In my template my ng-model="search.name" but it should work to just watch search. But i dont have any scope for search on angular side? Should I ?

Comment: You should create a scope for search because it's an object. so in your controller initialize $scope.search = {name: ''}.  Also watch search.name rather than search, this is because watching an object is rather inefficient when you can watch just the value.

Comment: The other reason why you should watch search.name rather than search is because of the newValue variable.  Unless you watch this to return the search object, then watch search.

Comment: Still without results, I has to be my fault, I am still newbe if it goes aobut angular, i used your shorter code from plunker but is still the same issue after typing something into ng-model search object brylanty is disappearing

Comment: Maybe you should try to recreate the issue you have in plunker and present it here so we can diagnose better exactly where you are at fault.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** Added [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zxuma20n/1/)

According to [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

You can watch any variable by doing something like

```
$scope.$watch(function(){

    return $scope.hf_directory; // or Directories.hf_directory if Directory is a factory/service 

}, function(newVal, oldVal){
    if(newVal != oldVal){
        $scope.newestValue = newVal;  // Do some cool UI
    }

}, true); // true to check object equality (see below)
```

**object equality** is equivalent to angular.equal [Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals)

I hope this helps.

Comment: it not working with object hf_directory but i change it with search and then something happens object brylanty which should get new value disappearing, $.scope.search = {} is enough? i dont want to specify it cause i want all ng-model witch search.something1 search.something2 work

Comment: Yes, just replace $scope.hf_directory with $scope.search. I added a demo in the answer.

Comment: Could you add some scope with data to your fiddle? I am not sure if understand your code correctly, but where should i put there some scope object with value which will be change?

Comment: I forgot to include Angular in the demo. Check again. Type something in both inputs.

Comment: I see, but how it would work with some real data, we can suppose you have to scope objects with the same data, one will be updated by search filter and another by watch function, actually i am doing this cause i have a directive that cannot be change naturally by | filter:search. I know i am quite problematic probably, i really appreciate your help ;) Maybe you can tell me what can i do or how to explain the issue so you will have more knowledge how to help me.

Comment: You can filter/search and then watch their objects. I think this is what you mean. The changed value are in the console, rather than alert. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zxuma20n/4/)